# Getting "405 Method Not Allowed" from post request to .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing a new web api in .Net Core, having previously worked with .Net Framework.

I have a post endpoint that should take a json object from the body of the request and does some stuff with it, but I never reach my endpoint and only get the response "405 Method Not Allowed" when I test it in postman.

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PageHitController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IMongoCollection<PageHit> pageHitsCollection;

        public PageHitController(IMongoClient _client)
        {
            var mongoDB = _client.GetDatabase("POC_MongoDB");
            pageHitsCollection = mongoDB.GetCollection<PageHit>("PageHits"); 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/pagehit")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddPageHit([FromBody] PageHit pageHit)
        {
            // Do Stuff
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Expected object:

```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class PageHit
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("clientid")]
        public Guid ClientID { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("domain")]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("sessionid")]
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("pagesize")]
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
    builder
    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyOrigin();
}));
```

[image: postman response]

Please can you help me. All my GET endpoints are working fine, but this POST is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to fix the action route attribute. You can remove  [Route("api/pagehit")] attribute, make it default action

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> AddPageHit([FromBody] PageHit pageHit)
```

or fix the route attribute

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("~/api/addpagehit")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> AddPageHit([FromBody] PageHit pageHit)
```

in this case you will have to change pagehit to addpagehit in postman too

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something stupidly simple. I had no issues at all with routing in .Net Framework, and for some reason since switching to Core I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Accepted now. You answered so quickly I wasn't allowed to at first!